# Disable taking screenshots on mobile using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot

I saw on Facebook and other apps that Don't allow users to taking screenshots. When we swipe down 3 fingers, or click power button and volume Down btn together, it says "Taking Screenshots is not allowed by the app or your organisation". How do they do it.

I saw one code / pen on Codepen where I saw the developer did it using javascript / jquery. It's been 6 months and I forgot the URL of the pen.

Oh, I know how to disable prntscr key on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to block taking screenshot on websites through JavaScript. The only way you might be able to do it is only if you are displaying the website in your own app on Android, it is possible to set `FLAG_SECURE` in your code. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE). Just mind the fact that any rooted device would be able to go around it anyway.

Also [here's related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764715/how-can-you-prevent-screen-captures-on-the-web-2020) about trying to block screenshots on web.

Comment: thanks. So how Facebook app did it...?   In lock profile, you can't never take a screenshots. Whether the device is rooted or not.

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus Rooted device requires also some kind of magisk module to override the `FLAG_SECURE` or custom ROM that just ignores it all together.